# Obtain total formik error count within a fieldarray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Given the following Yup validation setup which has a nested Formik FieldArray:

```
  parentLevel: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object({
      childrenLevel: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.object({
          childName: Yup.string().required('Name is required'),
          childAge: Yup.number().required('Age is required')
        })
      )
    })
  )
```

I need to calculate the total formik errors found within the `childrenLevel` fieldarray.

For example, assuming the user presses a "Add Children" button twice for FieldArray `childrenLevel` and enters no information for both Child Name and Age for those two records, I would like to obtain the error count from formik of `2 errors`.

Here is the error object for the above:

```
   "props": {
        "parentLevel": [
            {
                "childrenLevel": [
                    {
                        "childName": "Name is required",
                        "childAge": "Age is required",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "childrenLevel": [
                    {
                        "childName": "Name is required",
                        "childAge": "Age is required",
                    }                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Unsure how to approach this using `errors.parentLevel` or `errors.childrenLevel` to determine total errors within `childrenLevel`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the errors object within the Formik context and use the parentLevel property to access the errors for the parent level field array. Iterate through it and use `childrenLevel` property to access children errors.

Now for the total errors, use Object.values() on childrenLevel field array and count its length.

```
Object.values(formik.errors.parentLevel)
  .map(parent => Object.values(parent.childrenLevel))
  .reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.length, 0);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I included the error object to my question above. Unsure if this will help with your solution?

Comment: How about you flatten and uniq the errors in childrenLevel and count the length?

Comment: Sorry, unsure what you mean exactly. Are you able to please provide some additional information/example.